# How to add Request Headers in filter and get that header in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am Using following wrapper to add headers its adding headers in request

```
final class MutableHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    // holds custom header and value mapping
    private final Map<String, String> customHeaders;

    public MutableHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
        super(request);
        this.customHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public void putHeader(String name, String value){
        this.customHeaders.put(name, value);
    }

    public String getHeader(String name) {
        // check the custom headers first
        String headerValue = customHeaders.get(name);

        if (headerValue != null){
            return headerValue;
        }
        // else return from into the original wrapped object
        return ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeader(name);
    }

    public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
        // create a set of the custom header names
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(customHeaders.keySet());

        // now add the headers from the wrapped request object
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Enumeration<String> e = ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeaderNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            // add the names of the request headers into the list
            String n = e.nextElement();
            set.add(n);
        }

        // create an enumeration from the set and return
        return Collections.enumeration(set);
    }
}
```

with filter

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    MutableHttpServletRequest mutableRequest = new MutableHttpServletRequest(req);
    ...
    mutableRequest.putHeader("x-user-id", "1");
    chain.doFilter(mutableRequest, response);
}
```

but i cant able to get that header in contoller its giving null
so anyone please tell me how to set headers in filter and access that header in controller.

```
 @GetMapping("/api1/temp1")
        private ResponseEntity<Object>  temp1(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, @RequestHeader(value="x-user-id",required=false) String userId){
            System.out.println(userId));
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>("temp1 method", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you make a request to controller, first OPTIONS request is sent, in which filter will not found values which you have set.
Fist skip the option request then try.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        if(!"OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
    MutableHttpServletRequest mutableRequest = new MutableHttpServletRequest(req);
    ...
    mutableRequest.putHeader("x-user-id", "1");
    chain.doFilter(mutableRequest, response);
        }
}
```

Comment: actually i am using postman for sending request and i can get all headers passed through postman but cant able to get headers that are added by using wrapper in controller please look into it and share me your opinion.thanks

Comment: and i am only forwarding get request by adding header x-user-id rest of the request type i am not forwarding them at all directly sending reponse to POST,OPTION,PUT and DELETE method type so thats not issue i guess

Answer (score 0):

Override getHeaders() in MutableHttpServletRequest class
to get value using @RequestHeader.

```
// MutableHttpServletRequest class
...
@Override
public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet();
    if (customHeaders.keySet().contains(name)) {
        set.add(getHeader(name));
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Enumeration<String> e = ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeaders(name);
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String n = e.nextElement();
        set.add(n);
    }
    return Collections.enumeration(set);
}
...
```

And this page help for you
https://neunggu.tistory.com/50

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `HttpServletRequestWrapper#getHeaders(String name)` method and return `customHeader` value alongside with other headers values.

```java
public class MoreHeadersHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final Map<String, String> headers;

    public MoreHeadersHttpServletRequestWrapper(
        HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, String> headers) {
      super(request);
      this.headers = Map.copyOf(headers);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
      return headers.getOrDefault(name, super.getHeader(name));
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
      Set<String> extended = new HashSet<>();
      Optional.ofNullable(headers.get(name)).ifPresent(extended::add);
      Enumeration<String> headers = super.getHeaders(name);
      while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
        String value = headers.nextElement();
        extended.add(value);
      }
      return Collections.enumeration(extended);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
      Set<String> extended = new HashSet<>(headers.keySet());
      Enumeration<String> headerNames = super.getHeaderNames();
      while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
        extended.add(headerName);
      }
      return Collections.enumeration(extended);
    }
  }
```